# JQuery show drop-down menu based on current section ID

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, navbar

I have different sections in a one-page structure and the nav-bar is categorized with drop-down lists for each category.
I want to show the drop-down menu of the category the current section belongs to.

```
if($("#About").hasClass('active')){
    $(".tab-menu-content").css("display","block");
}
```

I tried to implement it this way but it's not working, any ideas?
Thank you

Edit:
I am really sorry but I can't post the code here, I will try to explain it in more details. [As you can see I has a nav menu with drop-down menus on hover.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KW5Mw.png)

[I want to show the drop menu contents automatically when I reach it's sections without hovering. Can this be done?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFFLz.png)

Comment: show your html please

Comment: clarify the question by providing more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Here](https://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=bdf87fac1d4a019a715108ad5f95eff3)** is he live demo of what you are asking. I tried to keep JS as simple as possible. By using only if functions i detect if the sub category is not active then active it, also by clicking itself or other categories it slides them up.

**EDIT:** I updated the code as you want to display the sections subcategories as you scroll but it may seem a little confusing. Check out and ask if you have trouble with code.

HTML

```
 <nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="category">Category 1
      <div class="subcategory">
        <ul>
          <li class="width-li">Sub 1</li>
          <li>Sub 2</li>
          <li>Sub 3</li>
          <li>Sub 4</li>
          <li>Sub 5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="category">Category 2
      <div class="subcategory">
        <ul>
          <li>Sub 1</li>
          <li>Sub 2</li>
          <li>Sub 3</li>
          <li>Sub 4</li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="category">Category 3
      <div class="subcategory">
        <ul>
          <li>Sub 1</li>
          <li>Sub 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="category">Category 4
      <div class="subcategory">
        <ul>
          <li>Sub 1</li>
          <li>Sub 2</li>
          <li>Sub 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="containers" id="red"></div>
<div class="containers" id="blue"></div>
<div class="containers" id="green"></div>
<div class="containers" id="yellow"></div>
```

CSS

```
body{
  background:white;
  margin:0;
}
nav{
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  background:#E67B73;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
}
.category{
  display:block;
  width:25%;
  height:100%;
  float:left;
  line-height:40px;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bolder;
  transition:background 0.5s;
  cursor:pointer;
  position:relative;
}
.category:hover{
  background:#E65273;
}
.active-category{
  background:#E65273;
}
.subcategory{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  background:#EEAAA3;
  display:none;
  top:40px;
  left:0;
}
.subcategory li{
  width:20%;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}
.subcategory li:hover{
  background:#FFAAA3;
}
.containers{
  width:100%;
  height:calc(100vh - 40px);
}
#red{
  background:red;
  margin-top:40px;
}
#blue{
  background:blue;
}
#green{
  background:green;
}
#yellow{
  background:yellow;
}
```

JS

```
$('.category').click(function(){
  $('.active').slideToggle(50);
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $('.active-category').removeClass('active-category');
  if($(this).children('.subcategory').hasClass('self') == false){
    $('.self').removeClass('self');
    $(this).children('.subcategory').slideToggle(500).addClass('active self');
    $(this).addClass('active-category');
  } else {
    $('.self').removeClass('self');
  }
});
$(document).scroll(function(){
  var scrolled = $(document).scrollTop();
  var contheight = $('.containers').height();
  switch(true){
    case (scrolled<contheight):
      selection(0);
      break;
    case (scrolled<contheight*2):
      selection(1);
      break;
    case (scrolled<contheight*3):
      selection(2);
      break;
    case (scrolled<contheight*4):
      selection(3);
      break;
             }
});
function selection(e){
  if($('.category').eq(e).hasClass('active-category') == false){
    $('.active').slideToggle(50);
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.active-category').removeClass('active-category');
    $('.category').eq(e).addClass('active-category');
    if($('.category').eq(e).children('.subcategory').hasClass('self') == false){
      $('.self').removeClass('self');
      $('.category').eq(e).children('.subcategory').slideToggle().addClass('active self');
    } else {
      $('.self').removeClass('self');
    }
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, imagine a link under category one list, which is an ID href to a section in the website. I want to list to show itself when I reach that sections ID, without clicking the menu. That means when I scroll to any section, its corresponding drop-down menu should appear without hovering or clicking.

Comment: @RaghadBogery Updated.

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I needed. Can I ask what is class ".self"?

Comment: Without self class when you click and open 1 category and click it again to close it, it slides up and slides down again because without it we don't know if we clicked itself again to close it. Self class is the control parameter. You can remove it and try to see the effect.